# passing data into the constructor gives me undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, frontend

I am retrieving data from the server in the `constructor`, and passing those date into a variable, but when I tried to use it in the outer scope, it keep giving `undefined`. I need to get the `userID` from the profile data, how can I solve this?

```
constructor(
  public service: OrderService,
  private dialog: MatDialog,
  private toastr: ToastrService,
  public UserService: UserService,
) {
  // get user details, to get user Order
  this.UserService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.userDetails = res as[],
      console.log(this.userDetails.id)
      this.userId = this.userDetails.id;
      console.log(this.userId)
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err.err);
    }
  );
}

testPrintUserID() {
  console.log(this.userId)
}
```

Comment: When are you calling the method `testPrintUserID` ? Make sure you have received the data first when you make the function call.

Comment: how do I wait till i get the data

Comment: Depends on where you are going to use it and how. 
If you want to execute any task after receiving the data, make sure your logic is inside the `subscribe`.
If you are going to use it on template (html), you can directly use async pipe as well

Comment: 1. Not advisable to perform async operations in the constructor. 2 Make sure you are using that variable after the response is received.